# Routing URL Requests using Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I have been working on implementing [PyTeaser](https://github.com/xiaoxu193/PyTeaser) as an API so can send requests using my program to get a summary of an article. I have been trying to figure out how to send url requests to the API using flask. I was having trouble routing my url request because I didn't really understand what goes in the ???? under app route section below so that I can route my requests.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from PyTeaser import SummarizeUrl
from PyTeaser import Summarize

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('????', methods=['GET'])
def summary_url(url):
   summary = SummarizeUrl(url)
   return jsonify({'title': title, 'url': url, 'summaries': summary})


@app.route('????', methods=['GET'])
def summary(title, text):
  summary = Summarize(title, text)
    return jsonify({'title': title, 'summaries': summary})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,app.run(host='0.0.0.0'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
@app.route('/<url>')
```

I'm not sure second route as it looks like you want to take in two variables. 
But possibly:

```
@app.route('/<title>/<text>')
```

Comment: So I got that inside my script and the server is running. But that would my format for request be? Something like:
example.com:5000/http://www.cnn.com/2015/05/03/politics/trade-john-boehner-hillary-clinton-barack-obama/index.html

Comment: That might not work sense there are slashes. The first example would only take in one variable between :5000/ and the next slash, in that case it would take in cnn.com.Is it possible to receive json? If you can send json to one of your routes with the information, that might be a better solution.